# How is the word 'gullet' understood by non-medical English speakers?

Tags: meaning, differences, british-english, medical

I've found that there are several dialect words that mean both  'windpipe' and 'gullet'.  This is true of [Wright's (old, but monumental) dialect dictionary](https://eddonline-proj.uibk.ac.at/edd/termsOfUse.jsp) (see e.g. 'kecker'). It also holds in a monograph on body parts in the later German dialects (some of which transfer into English.  Can someone help me pin down the accepted lay terms and understandings of the region around the epiglottis, trachea and oesophagus?

Comment: Gullet sounds like a chicken body part. I’ve never heard it before and I read quite a lot.

Comment: I once saw a person threaten to slit someone else's _weasand_ in a novel set around 1890. It was one of the Mazo de la Roche "Jalna" series, written in the 1950s, belonging to my mother. Wikipedia says: "obsolete as regards human anatomy, but current in the meatpacking industry".

Comment: Throat, windpipe and gullet. Though if you asked a layman to draw a diagram ... or even mark them on an unlabelled diagram ....

Comment: I understand it to mean the food pipe (oesophagus), not the windpipe (conformed by Oxford Dictionaries). Something you can't swallow 'sticks in your gullet'.

Comment: Following your terms it is the oesophagus. But I understand gullet better.

Comment: I hear "gullet" occasionally, and I interpret it to mean "throat".  "It sticks in my gullet" is a semi-common expression.

Answer (score 1):

It is common for many anatomical words that belong to almost all animals to be thought of as only belonging to only a few. Turkeys have their gullets addressed each holiday by the cook. That those who feast on the results also have them is not always clear. My favorite is the notion that only beetles have a thorax. Though it could be most of their body it is just a region as it is in humans where thoracic surgery is a large subject. Each part of the throat in humans can almost always be found in other critters, the closer they are evolutionally the more likely.

According to thefreedictionary on epiglottis
"Swallowing closes the opening to the trachea [windpipe, front of the neck below the chin] by placing the larynx [flap] against the epiglottis. This prevents food and drink from entering the larynx and trachea, directing it instead into the esophagus" and to the stomach.

The gullet is the tube going from just below the vocal chords to the stomach. It is used less medically to mean anywhere between the mouth and the stomach, even to include the stomach where the food rests.

Comment: Great thoughts here, thanks.  Weasand can denote both the windpipe and the gullet.  There's a good  thread about this at http://www.wordorigins.org/index.php/forums/viewthread/4575/  where you can see both windpipe and gullet clearly represented, so the confusion is not in the linguistics but in the discourse.   I think the broadest view is safest, i.e. the whole stretch from mouth to 'the insides'.  In the human anatomy I learned as a medical  student there was no such thing as a 'throat' (no 'insides', and no 'bottom'!).